# React proptypes component vs element

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

What is the difference between :

```
var Icon = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    name: React.PropTypes.string
  },
  render: function(){
    return (
      <span className={'glyphicon glyphicon-'+this.props.name}></span>
    );
  }
});

var Button = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    content: React.PropTypes.element // This one?
    content: React.PropTypes.component // Or this one?
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
       <button>{content}</button>
    );
  }
});
```

I'd like to use;

```
<Button content={<Icon name="heart" />} />
```

In which case should I use the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should render the Button like this:

```
var Button = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
       <button>{this.props.children}</button>
    );
  }
});
```

Then you can use it with an `<Icon />` or anything else (text...) :

```
<Button><Icon name="heart" /></Button>
```

or

```
<Button>anything</Button>
```

And then the correct proptype depends on what you want to allow inside your `<Button />`
(But I'm not sure `React.PropTypes.component` exists, it's not in the documentation: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html)

Comment: Indeed, `React.PropTypes.component` is not in the doc. It is in the Sublime JSX snippets, but they may be wrong. Using `this.props.children` seems like a much better solution indeed!

Comment: Actually, I think it was in the docs, but since React 0.12 `React.PropTypes.component` was renamed `React.PropTypes.element`.  It is certainly in the docs now.  While in general using children is usually a good solution there are certain times when passing in named components as props will allow you to do things you can't by simply nesting children.  For example, you might need to compose a page component by passing in header and footer components as props which then allows you to render the page with different headers and footers (without requiring a different page component for each page).